# C++ и русские символы

Tags: c++, unicode, scanf, wchar-t

Предположим имеется следующий код, почему если его выполнить, и ввести, например `ваыёё`, то программа завершится, будто бы, пропустив оставшиеся два `wscanf`?

```
int main ()
{
    wchar_t str [80];
    int i;

    wscanf (L"%ls",str);
    wscanf (L"%d",&i);
    wscanf (L"%x",&i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам wchar_t??? Это ж не юникод. И что за ось???

Comment: @Ljil Ubuntu 18.04